# 2009 Ford Escape Hybrid - Ignition Coils and Spark Plug Replacement

Tags: sparkplugs, ignition-coil, replacements, installation

I've purchased the parts and done my research. Basically, I am seeking some insight here to gauge if my understanding of the procedure is sufficient, that I have acquired all the necessary parts, and to get some tips/tricks/warnings to make sure I don't cause additional damage.

**Parts**

1. 4 vehicle-matched ignition coils
2. 4 vehicle-matched spark plugs
3. Replacement intake valve cover gaskets
4. Replacement EGR valve gasket
5. Dielectric grease

**Tools**

1. Torque wrench
2. Matching spark plug socket

**Procedure**

1. Disconnect and remove intake valve cover (I know this step contains several steps within it, but for brevity I am simply summarizing it as this)
2. Protect intake valves
3. Disconnect cables and bolts from each ignition coil - note which cable belongs to which
4. Use socket to remove and replace spark plugs
5. Apply dielectric grease to end of coil boots and reinstall; insert bolts and tighten with torque wrench
6. Clean intake surface, apply gasket to cover, reinstall
7. Reconnect all cables, retainers, etc. - tighten with torque wrench. Also clean EGR valve surfaces and install new gasket
8. Once all parts and covers replaced, test engine waiting for a clean idle, test drive

**Key things I want to know:**

1. Steps where I should exercise more caution; trouble points; high risk of damaging vehicle points
2. Complexity of this repair
3. Anything else that will help me execute this successfully

I think I have a good idea of what and how to do this. Quoted cost of this repair was enough of a sticker shock to send me looking for DIY solutions.

Thank you in advance for your replies and advice, and I apologize for any mistakes in the above - I'm not a mechanic by any means.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the right torque on the plugs. Over and under tightening can cause significant damage. Follow the intake bolt pattern and torque. Remove plugs when engine is cold. If plugs are really tight, take it easy. Loosen in 1/4 turn increments and shoot some rust penetrant onto the threads. Using muscle on stuck plugs can damage the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a good procedure planned out and you are planning on using a torque wrench (lots of shadetree mechanics get it done without the torque wrench. Go for it and get it done! Make sure you do not drop any objects down the hole while the spark plugs are removed as you can ruin the nengine if a bolt or rock gets in there.